# Can Power BI generate PDFs like SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

**SCENARIO:** a company is using SSRS to generate paycheck at the end of the month.

Every month SSRS generate 1 PDF per employee with the name, surname and how much he/she will be paid. the company has about 500 employees so there a re 500 PDFs that are generated.

**PROBLEM:** the company now wants  to [move to Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/migrate-ssrs-reports-to-power-bi) Is it possible to generate PDFs dynamically, one for each employee, form Power BI?

Comment: in theory, yes. there's an [ExportToFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file) API endpoint that takes PDF as one of the options, you should probably be able to work something out with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for Paginated Reports: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi

Comment: Thank you @David. In the video I can see that I can download the report `51721` so yes, it can dynamically create reports. But if I have 500 employees do I have to input each number from the web interface with a web crawler (let's say with a python script that input the `51721` and then download each PDF) or can I input that in the URL or make an API call that generates the report and download in PDF?

Comment: This video should answer all your questions. You can download a single pdf and use a pdf splitter to split by page to get all 500 employees in one go. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSIbRNXGgPQ

Comment: Right, I think that video is even mentioning that the Export API is even better: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file#fileformat and will probably be our go-to solution.